# Cutting polygons in same isochrone map layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, isochrone, osmtools

I've created some travel time isochrones using the 'OSM Tools' plugin in QGIS. I now need to remove overlapping sections of the isochrone layer so that I'm left with discrete polygons for each isochrone (in this case travel time to a central point). This is so I can calculate the proportion of a 'district' that is within x and y and z, mins of the city centre. So for example here are my isochrones

[image: this is my starting point]

If I now remove the 'shortest travel time' (yellow polygon) it's clear that all other polygons depicting travel times in excess of the yellow polygon are beneath:

[image]

I would like to cookie cut out the longer travel time polygons so that none of the individual isochrones overlap i.e. my layer looks like this (with the yellow isochrone hidden):

[image]

I had thought that the difference or symmetrical differnece tool would do the trick but no joy. Is there an easy way to cut/clip polygons on the same layer from within QGIS?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To modify topologically incorrect polygons (overlapping polygons) as in the following example:

[image]

you need to use `GRASS -> v.clean` tool from `Processing toolbox -> GRASS GIS 7 commands -> Vector -> v.clean`, and in cleaning tool use `Break`, as you can see below:

[image]

The output result is now topologically correct:

[image]

Comment: thanks this is really helpful. Next stage: can you think of an easy way of automating deletion of those overlapping polygons i.e. the polygons are now split where they intersect, but I now need to delete the overlapping polygons - preferably not manually...

Comment: Try to use `Delete duplicate geometries` from `QGIS Toolbox -> QGIS geoalgorithms -> Vector general tools -> Delete duplicate geometries`. It may solve the problem.

Comment: that nearly does what I want, although that tool does not consider attributes of my data, so it just deletes everything except the lowest layer:( Are there any more complex operations I can perform to specify what data to delete?

Answer (score 11):

Use 'Clipper' plugin. Install it from "Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins". (I use QGIS 2.18)

After installing, select center polygon and click on the Clipper button on the Plugin Toolbar

[image]

Then select other outer polygon and click button and so on.

[image]

Result:

[image]